# Solr 5.x, how to generate .war file

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, solr, lucene

I know that Solr do not provide any .war file anymore, but I have a project where Solr is included as a war dependency and the whole webapp is deployed in a web server, and I need to upgrade Solr from 4.10.3 to 5.x.

Refactoring the project to use a stand alone Solr would be very painful, does anybody know how to generate a .war file for Solr 5.x?

Comment: did you check out the code for solr5.x?

Comment: yes, I did and I followed the procedure in https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToCompileSolr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the source code from

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_3

Note : check out for your version there.

Use 'ant dist' to build the project WAR and JAR files.

Comment: I needed Solr 5.x not 3.3

Comment: yes for your version you can check which is you need when your try to checkout the code try this...http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_5_3

Comment: I already did it ( checked the code out from http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_5_3)

Comment: how? I already followed the instructions here https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToCompileSolr and I did not find any .war in 'dist' folder

Comment: I didnt follow any steps from any link...they have given the build.xml..use the same to generate the war...I think in the current version they are using the maven...

Comment: well, in the newest version the ant build does not produce any .war, you can find only the exploded webapp folder

Comment: what java version you have?

Answer (score 1):

First of all Solr is a DBMS and [with step from version 4.x to 5.x it does not (longer) want to be deployed as war-file.](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Major+Changes+from+Solr+4+to+Solr+5#MajorChangesfromSolr4toSolr5-SolrisNowaStandaloneServer)

But the main reason why Solr switch from war-file to "Standalone Server" is [that the community does not want to answer questions about servlet container.](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/WhyNoWar)

So Solr has still the structure of a (jetty) web application and you could generate your war-file by reinsert the ''dist''-Task in ant build.xml-files or by hand.

### Steps "by hand" to build war-File

- download `solr-6.0.0.zip` and extract
- copy `server\lib\ext\*` to `server\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\lib`
- create `classes` in  `server\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF`
- copy `server\resources\log4j.properties` to new `classes` folder
- change `solr.log` in `log4j.properties`
- change in `web.xml` the solr-home (order of child-elements is important)

  `<env-entry>
     <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
     <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
     <env-entry-value>/home/solr/solr60home</env-entry-value>
  </env-entry>`

Comment: I followed your steps, but where is .War file?

Comment: Last steps: zip all below "webapp" and name this file "solr.war"